# SSRS displaying data in a table when grouped by year

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, bids

The below image shows the table in design view followed by how it looks when run. My problem is that if you look for example under the first 'Service' listed for February, there is a line for 2010's data then a separate lower line for the 2011 data.

I need the table to make use of the one line for that particular Month rather than splitting the data.

[image]

Comment: Found out that I needed to right click on Details in row groups and add my month field to use one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that I needed to right click on Details in row groups and add my month field to use one row.